# Checking if words are present in a list and if string integer present

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

The idea is to find specific words whether or not are present in a list of sentences.

Also, as another output find string integers.

Code to find the presence of words in a list

```
import pandas as pd
import re

info = ['Crafting a compelling job description is essential to helping you attract the most qualified candidates for your job. With more than 25 million jobs listed on Indeed, a great job description can help your jobs stand out from the rest. Your job descriptions are where you start marketing your company and your job to your future hire.']

df = pd.DataFrame(info,columns=['One'])

df['New_Col'] = df.One.str.contains('jobs', flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex = True, na = False)


save = []
for i,e in enumerate(info):
    save.append(e.isdigit())
df['New_Col2'] = save
```

Output:

```
info
Out[40]: ['Crafting a compelling job description is essential to helping you attract the most qualified candidates for your job. With more than 25 million jobs listed on Indeed, a great job description can help your jobs stand out from the rest. Your job descriptions are where you start marketing your company and your job to your future hire.']
```

Output

```
                                                 One  New_Col  New_Col2
0  Crafting a compelling job description is essen...     True     False
```

Summary: ideally it would be nice to automate it in a way that I just feed the regex contains with a list of words that should be looking for. (e.g. ['jobs','employement'] and so on), which can be done with format function and loop it through. However, I'm not a big fan of regex, probably apply the function would make more sense. All in all, any better way of tackling such an issue is benefitial

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: The `split` method, iterating through a list, and checking for numeric contents, are all contained in introductory tutorials.

Comment: I haven't specified the question properly my bad, I've fixed that issue! @Prune

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
code  = "One Two Three \n59 results 46"
res = [int(s) for s in code .split() if s.isdigit()]
print(res)
```

result:

```
[59, 46]
```

Comment: Yes which can be later added to the data frame. However,  what would happen in case words are detected that aren't present in our initial list of words that we are looking for, that regex flags as present.@Rushikesh Talokar